# Why does `dd` map 200M of virtual address space?

Tags: linux, memory

1. `sudo atop -R`
2. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null    # in a background tab`

In `atop`, type `m` for memory details.  Type `/dd` to search for `dd`.  Result:

`PID    TID  MINFLT  MAJFLT  VSTEXT  VSLIBS   VDATA  VSTACK   VSIZE   RSIZE   PSIZE   VGROW   RGROW  SWAPSZ  RUID      EUID       MEM  CMD        1/1` 
... 
`29041      -      93       0     56K   1456K    176K    136K  210.0M    832K    255K  210.0M    832K      0K  alan-sys  alan-sys    0%  dd`

Let's snip the columns down to what I am most curious about:

`PID    VSTEXT  VSLIBS   VDATA  VSTACK   VSIZE   RSIZE   PSIZE   VGROW   RGROW  SWAPSZ` 
... 
`29041     56K   1456K    176K    136K  210.0M    832K    255K  210.0M    832K      0K`

What is this 210M VSIZE for?

---

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides $(which dd)
coreutils-8.30-6.fc29.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not a heap memory allocation.  It was a virtually mapped file of locale information.  The mapped file was `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`.  It is owned by the package `glibc-all-langpacks`.  I.e. this is probably a file of messages in different languages.

```
$ gdb dd
...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x29c0: file ../src/dd.c, line 2380.
(gdb) run if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
Starting program: /usr/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
warning: Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffd3b8) at ../src/dd.c:2380
2380    {
(gdb)  break mmap
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7ecd070: file ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c, line 41.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __GI___mmap64 (addr=addr@entry=0x0, len=len@entry=217742304, prot=prot@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=2, fd=fd@entry=3, 
    offset=offset@entry=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c:41
41  {
(gdb) break munmap
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7ffff7ecd150: file ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S, line 78.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 30592
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
      0x555555554000     0x555555556000     0x2000        0x0 /usr/bin/dd
      0x555555556000     0x555555562000     0xc000     0x2000 /usr/bin/dd
      0x555555562000     0x555555567000     0x5000     0xe000 /usr/bin/dd
      0x555555567000     0x555555568000     0x1000    0x12000 /usr/bin/dd
      0x555555568000     0x555555569000     0x1000    0x13000 /usr/bin/dd
      0x555555569000     0x55555558a000    0x21000        0x0 [heap]
      0x7fffeae2d000     0x7ffff7dd5000  0xcfa8000        0x0 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
...
(gdb) exit
```